# Removing Class Path and Module Path from an Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, module-path

I am trying to import some files into a java project that I created in eclipse. Other students in my class have indicated that when they go into their project properties, they do not have "classpath" and "modulepath", allowing them to add the files that they need directly into their project, both as direct files or as JAR files.

Whenever I make a Java Project, I always have these two options appear in my properties. While this may be fine, whenever I try to import the necessary folders into either path, I get errors. For example, I am trying to import files that will allow me to play .wav files in my program. But whenever the program runs, and an event would trigger the sound to play, I receive errors saying that the file I am referencing was not found.

How can I set up my project so that I do not have "classpath" or "modulepath" as options in my project properties? I think this is the root of my issue.

Comment: The _Modulepath_ exists since Java 9. So for a Java 8 project, you won't have the two options because everything is on the classpath. If you use a higher Java version, delete the `module-info.java` file and put everything on the classpath.

Comment: A file not found error for the .wav file is just a problem with the file path you are specifying, nothing to do with classpath/modulepath entries.